# Templates not loading in the ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am working in angularjs, of course, and following are the index.php (after logging in) and mainApp.js (main application after logging in). Here I am using session storage to check whether the current session is valid or not. Moreover, after logging in, the parent page, i.e. the one rendered by index.php is visible along with its navigational bar, but the templates are no where to be found. The google development tools show that the templates have been loaded successfully (i.e. status 200) and one can see the in the network's tab. But the templates are not rendered no matter what you select from navigational bar.

**index.php**

```
   <!-- main page -->
<?php
    $version = time();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap and our custon css files) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .navbar {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/mainApp.js"></script>


</head>
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<body>
<div ng-app="mainApp">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><strong>DASHBOARD</strong></a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Client
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a ui-sref="addClient">Add Client</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Service
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a ui-sref="addService">Add Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ui-sref="logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT -->
    <div ui-view></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mainApp.js**

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);

mainApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================

        .state('home', {
            url:'/',
            templateUrl: function (){
                if(sessionStorage.username!=="karan" || sessionStorage.password!=="123456"){
                    return 'templates/login.html';
                }
                else {
                    return 'templates/home.html';

                }
            }
        })

        .state('addClient', {
            url:'/addClient',
            templateUrl: function(){
                if(sessionStorage.username!=="karan" || sessionStorage.password!=="123456"){
                    return 'templates/login.html';
                }
                else{
                    return 'templates/addClient.html';
                }
            }
        })

        .state('addService', {
            url:'/addService',
            templateUrl: function(){
                if(sessionStorage.username!=="karan" || sessionStorage.password!=="123456"){
                    return 'templates/login.html';
                }
                else{
                    return 'templates/addService.html';
                }
            }
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: function (){
                if(sessionStorage.username!=="karan" || sessionStorage.password!=="123456"){
                    return 'templates/login.html';
                }
                else {
                    return 'templates/about.html';
                }
            }
        })

        .state('logout', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: function (){
                sessionStorage.clear();
                return 'templates/login.html';
            }
        });

});
```

**please tell me if there's any better way instead of using sessions and also help me solve this problem. Thank you.**

**P.S. on a side note, i am a newbie in angularjs and would appreciate if you can guide me in how to implement login most efficiently , both performance and security wise**

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this situation is adding an interceptor as follows.

```
mainApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loginInterceptor');
    }).factory('loginInterceptor', function ($q, $window,$rootScope) {
        return  {
            'response': function(response) { 
                if(sessionStorage.username!=="karan" || sessionStorage.password!=="123456"){
                   $rootScope.$broadcast("notLoggedIn",{statusCode : 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'});
                }
                else{
                  return response;
                }

            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
              return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    })
```

Then handle the message 'notLoggedIn' as follows

```
mainApp.run(function($state,$rootScope){
        $rootScope.$on("notLoggedIn",function(event,message){
        $state.transitionTo('login');//Define a state with template url 'templates/login.html';
    });
})
```

Advantage of this approach is, you will not end up checking the login status in every state definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using ng-view instead of ui-view and see if that makes a difference, it helped in my case.

Comment: That's not possible Morgan as i will need to reflect the associated changes in various files, which would be hectic.